# How to make child appear on top of the parent inside the table tr?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Table in the left menu which is having the Scroll bar and i have a Tooltip for each row inside a table. My requirement is to show **Tooltip** on **Top** of the **Scrollbar** towards right, but some how i am unable to achieve that.

Problem is Tooltip appearing behind the Scrollbar and body. I need to show it on top of the Scrollbar towards right.

I have a Position "Relative" for Parent Div and "Absolute" for Child element. Z-index also seems not working here.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ResultsWrapper">
  <table class="ResultsTable">
    <tr>
       <td class="hasTooltip">
          <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
             <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
             <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
         </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.SerialNumberContainer {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 10;
}

.SerialNumberTooltip {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 40px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    display: none;
}

.SerialNumberContainer:hover {
    z-index: 20;
}

.SerialNumberContainer:hover .SerialNumberTooltip {
    display: block;
    z-index: 40;
}
```

Please check the below Fiddle.

[Full Example In Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vw6naxmr/)

Appreciate your Help.

Comment: I dont think it is possible with this structure and only pure css

Comment: Try this `.SerialNumberTooltip {
    position: absolute;
    top: -22px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    display: none;
}`

Comment: Hi Awais, suggested code not working. I need to show Tooltip on top of the Scroll bar towards Right.Thanks

Comment: Hi Batu.khan, Please suggest if any other choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a wrapper *class* (*.TooltipWrapper* in the HTML) like the following way:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.SerialNumber').forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('mousemove',function(ele){
    var x = ele.pageY;
    el.parentNode.querySelector('.TooltipWrapper').style.top = `${x}px`;
  });
});
```

```css
.ResultsWrapper {
  width:150px;
  height:314px;
  text-align:center;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.ResultsTable {
  width:86px;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
.ResultsTable th, .ResultsTable td {
  border:1px solid black;
}
.ColumnSerialNo {
  width:81px;
}

.SerialNumber {
  width: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.TooltipWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  
}
.hasTooltip:hover .TooltipWrapper {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.SerialNumberTooltip {
  display: block;
  --margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: 85px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="ResultsWrapper">
  <table class="ResultsTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="ColumnSerialNo">Serial Number</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="hasTooltip">
          <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
            <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
            <div class="TooltipWrapper">
              <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hasTooltip">
          <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
            <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815207</div>
             <div class="TooltipWrapper">
              <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815207</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hasTooltip">
          <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
            <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815208</div>
             <div class="TooltipWrapper">
              <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815208</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hasTooltip">
          <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
            <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815209</div>
             <div class="TooltipWrapper">
              <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815209</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hasTooltip">
          <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
            <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815210</div>
             <div class="TooltipWrapper">
              <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815210</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hasTooltip">
          <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
            <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815211</div>
             <div class="TooltipWrapper">
              <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815211</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hasTooltip">
          <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
            <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815212</div>
             <div class="TooltipWrapper">
              <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815212</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hasTooltip">
          <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
            <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815213</div>
             <div class="TooltipWrapper">
              <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815213</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hasTooltip">
          <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
            <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815214</div>
             <div class="TooltipWrapper">
              <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815214</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hasTooltip">
          <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
            <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815215</div>
             <div class="TooltipWrapper">
              <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815215</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hasTooltip">
          <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
            <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815216</div>
             <div class="TooltipWrapper">
              <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815216</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hasTooltip">
          <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
            <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815217</div>
             <div class="TooltipWrapper">
              <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815217</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hasTooltip">
          <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
            <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815218</div>
             <div class="TooltipWrapper">
              <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815218</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hasTooltip">
          <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
            <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815219</div>
             <div class="TooltipWrapper">
              <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815219</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hasTooltip">
          <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
            <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815220</div>
             <div class="TooltipWrapper">
              <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815220</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hasTooltip">
          <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
            <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815221</div>
             <div class="TooltipWrapper">
              <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815221</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hasTooltip">
          <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
            <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815222</div>
             <div class="TooltipWrapper">
              <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815222</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hasTooltip">
          <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
            <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815223</div>
             <div class="TooltipWrapper">
              <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815223</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hasTooltip">
          <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
            <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815224</div>
             <div class="TooltipWrapper">
              <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815224</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hasTooltip">
          <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
            <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815225</div>
             <div class="TooltipWrapper">
              <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815225</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hasTooltip">
          <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
            <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815226</div>
             <div class="TooltipWrapper">
              <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815226</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Mamun, My Requirement is to show, Tool Tip on top of the Scrollbar towards right, Please help.

Comment: It is good but When we move the Scroll Bar, The Tooltip is not related to the Row. i mean, Tooltip is not moving along with the table row. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**This is the workaround:**
 1. Change html structure:

```
<div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
```

2. Using pseudo elements to target attribute of div .**(adding before after css)**
3. remove position:relative on which the tooltip was depending.
4. Removed top and left attribute as they depend on position relative and replace with margin .

> Below is the fixed code:

```css
.ResultsWrapper {
    width:150px;
    height:314px;
    text-align:center;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.ResultsTable {
    width:86px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.ResultsTable th, .ResultsTable td {
    border:1px solid black;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
.ColumnSerialNo {
    width:81px;
}

.SerialNumberContainer {
    z-index: 10;
}

.SerialNumber {
    width: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.SerialNumber:hover::before {
    position: absolute;
    content:attr(data-before-content);
    margin:10px 0 0 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    display: block;
    z-index:9999;
}
.SerialNumber:hover{}
```

```html
<div class="ResultsWrapper">
    <table class="ResultsTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="ColumnSerialNo">Serial Number</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="aaaaaaa3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber" data-before-content="3119985815206">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Sahil Dhir, Solution is good but tooltip is not moving along with the table row if we move the menu scroll bar. tooltip should be sticked with the respective row right.

Comment: according to the user experience when we scroll anything in a box the control goes to the scroll and not the current position of mouse and also to check a particular row the user need to put the mouse on it to see . Scroll + changing tooltip is not recommended..

Comment: Correct. Anyways i am trying to give x and y positions  for the tooltip dynamically. So that tooltip can take container height and width.

Comment: if you are open to use javascript that will be the best method , anyways if you want to use css this will be the right method. Kindly like and accept my answer if you like .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot position an element over the scrollbar using Position absolute and z-index.
If you want to show element on top of the scrollbar then you need to use position fixed element.

```css
.ResultsWrapper {
    width:150px;
    height:314px;
    text-align:center;
        overflow-y:scroll;
    border:1px solid black;
    z-index:-1;
}
.ResultsTable {
    width:86px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.ResultsTable th, .ResultsTable td {
    border:1px solid black;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
.ColumnSerialNo {
    width:81px;
}

.SerialNumberContainer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.SerialNumber {
    width: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.SerialNumberTooltip {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 70px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    display: none;
    z-index:99999999999;
}

.SerialNumberContainer:hover {
    z-index: 20;
}

.SerialNumberContainer:hover .SerialNumberTooltip {
    display: block;
    z-index: 40;
}
```

```html
<div class="ResultsWrapper">
    <table class="ResultsTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="ColumnSerialNo">Serial Number</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
                        <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
                        <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
                        <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
                        <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
                        <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
                        <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
                        <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
                        <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
                        <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
                        <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
                        <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
                        <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
                        <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
                        <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
                        <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
                        <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
                        <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
                        <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
                        <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
                        <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hasTooltip">
                    <div class="SerialNumberContainer">
                        <div class="SerialNumber">3119985815206</div>
                        <div class="SerialNumberTooltip">3119985815206</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Check the below jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/rajeevRF/eoc8yv5a/5/

Comment: Thanks Rajeev, but i need to show Tooltip beside the each row not at a fixed position. Do we have any options? Please help.

Comment: Sorry. I don't think this can be achieved.